# Git - Shortcut for Branch Off from Another Branch

Tags: git, version-control

Are the following two command blocks equivalent?

```
$ git checkout -b myfeature develop
```

and second command block.

```
$ git checkout develop
$ git checkout -b myfeature
```

Comment: Those two command blocks are not equivalent.

Comment: @evolutionxbox what's the difference?

Comment: Forgive me. They are. I didn’t notice `develop` in the first command block.

Comment: @evolutionxbox no worries :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but one-line command is faster — it does 1 checkout instead of 2. Also there could be difference due to a `post-checkout` hook.

Another set of equivalent commands are:

```
git branch myfeature develop
git checkout myfeature
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `git checkout -b <new_branch>` command, this will create a new branch based on the current branch you are located.

So if your current branch is named **develop** you can create a new branch named **feature** based on the branch **develop** like this: `git branch -b feature`